# How to make bins and histograms

Tags: python, math, matplotlib, bin

I need to make 200 bins that are evenly spaced and have my data be sorted into them, so that I can make a histogram out of he data. Can someone help me make a script that can make 200 bins and have data be sorted inside of them.

This is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l=[]
with open("testdata") as f:
    line = f.next()
    f.next()# skip headers
    nat = int(line.split()[0])
    print nat

    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
        if line.strip():
            l.append(map(float,line.split()[1:]))  

    b = 0
    a = 1

for b in range(53):
    for a in range(b+1,54):
        vector1 = (l[b][0],l[b][1],l[b][2])
        vector2 = (l[a][0],l[a][1],l[a][2])

        x = vector1
        y = vector2
        vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))

        dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))

        dp = dotProduct**.5
        print dp

        #data = dp
        #num_bins = 200 # <- number of bins for the histogram
        #plt.hist(data, num_bins)
        #plt.show()
```

Errors:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py:621:     DeprecationWarning: Use the new widget gtk.Tooltip
  self.tooltips = gtk.Tooltips()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vector_final", line 42, in <module>
plt.hist(data, num_bins)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2008, in hist
    ret = ax.hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align,    orientation, rwidth, log, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7098, in hist
    w = [None]*len(x)
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you are in the right direction with matplotlib. The numpy library is also very good for these. Both libraries have actual functions that do this for you. What have you researched?

Comment: I added the current code I have, the commented part at the bottom is where I am trying to make the bins but I am just getting errors, so i need to find anoother way to go about it.

Comment: Post your errors as well. This is a learning process! We are just here to help and we can only do that based on the information you give us.

Comment: I dont have to do it any specific way, I just want to make 200 evenly spaced bins, and for my program to know how many points fall in each range of the bins..

Comment: Can you show the top five lines of the file you are reading? Its not immediately obvious what you are doing in the double loop.

Comment: its actually reading 50+ vector coordinates and spitting out data. so do you want to see the kind of numbers its spitting out? or reading?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57530/discussion-between-paul-seeb-and-wana-b3-nerd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close. The only thing you are missing is storing your data and passing it to the histogram function correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l=[]
with open("testdata") as f:
    line = f.next()
    f.next()# skip headers
    nat = int(line.split()[0])
    print nat

    for line in f:
        # store striped line and only store if there is data on the line. 
        cleaned = line.strip() 
        if cleaned:
            # convert to float and remove characters in first index
            l.append(map(float,cleaned.split()[1:]))  

b = 0
a = 1

# create a list to store our calculations in
distances = []
num_vects = len(l)

for b in range(num_vects-1):
    for a in range(b+1,num_vects):
        vector1 = (l[b][0],l[b][1],l[b][2])
        vector2 = (l[a][0],l[a][1],l[a][2])

        x = vector1
        y = vector2
        vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))

        dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))

        dp = dotProduct**.5

        # store individual data point into the list of calculated distances            
        distances.append(dp)

# plot histogram
num_bins = 200 # <- number of bins for the histogram

# store useful data returned by the histogram function
(n, bins, patches) = plt.hist(distances, num_bins)
plt.show()
```

Comment: yooo can you make another chat room, I got a new problem that I can't solve.

Comment: Hiiii can you make a chat room again?

Comment: @Wana_B3_Nerd Ask a question and link it here. Ill try to take a look tomorrow.